# Сервис/ПО для проверки сайта со всевозможных устройств, бразуеров и тд

Tags: тестирование, оптимизация-сайтов, сервисы

Интересует сервис/ПО платное/бесплатное, которое бы помогло "протестировать" сайт. На баги в отображении, юзабилити итд.

Хочу просто вбить ссылку и чтоб сервис сам прогнал сайт по всевозможным комбинациям устройство+расширение экрана+версия браузера и тд.

И потом выдал результат и указал комбинацию, где он считает есть проблема.

Comment: Компьютер — не дизайнер, никак не может знать, что такое проблема. Всё это можно только делать вручную, а сервисы могут лишь немного облегчить ручной труд

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы программа проверила целиком сайт по всем возможным комбинациям с учетом багов в отображении и прочего? Задача чуть менее чем невыполнимая- придется подключать нейронную сеть, и даже если анализ одной страницы сайта будет занимать сотые доли секунды- на перебор всех возможных вариантов уйдет чуть меньше чем бесконечность времени.

Answer (score 1):

Тестирование - это сложная задача. Что-то можно автоматизировать, где-то придется это делать вручную. Это слишком объемная область для изучения.

Полностью автоматизировать наверное нет, но вот некоторые примеры:

- https://www.browserling.com/ - интерактивное тестирование
- **https://www.browserstack.com/** - мобильные и браузеры (эмуляция реальных стеков)
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/ - встроеный в chrome аудит
- https://validator.w3.org/ валидатор разметки

Для тестирования на основе оригинала всё же придется писать собственные тесты, а для перехвата ошибок можно использовать сервисы подобные [sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) или rollbar.

Для каждого типы тестирования есть свои инструменты и подходы. **Чтобы "вбить и всё сказали" - такого пока НЕТ**.

> Согласен с комментариями к вопросу, о субъективности многих оценок.